# Button press event with parameter not fired

Tags: sapui5

I am using an xml view (Form.view.xml) where i have a submit button:

```
    <mvc:View controllerName="articleIntroductionmdg.article.controller.Form" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
        xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" displayBlock="true" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:u="sap.ui.unified" xmlns="sap.m">
        <Page busy="{local>/busy}">
            <headerContent>
                <Text text="{path: 'local>/vendorName', formatter: '.formatter.getUser'}"/>
                <Button icon="sap-icon://customer"/>
            </headerContent>

    <Button type="Emphasized" text="{i18n>SubmitBtn}" press=".onSubmit($event, 'true')"></Button>

The event handler 'onSubmit' is defined in the controller:

        onSubmit: function (oStatus) {
                if ((oStatus) !== "false") {

                    this._validateForm();
                }
    }
```

I am calling the same 'onSubmit' from another 'common.js' file under the controller folder and it works:

```
onUploadCSV: function () {
this.onSubmit("false");
}
```

But when i try to fire the press the button from the Form.view.xml,

The even it self doesn't fire.

I checked the sapui5 document and its written that you can pass the parameter to the press event like:

```
<Button text="click" tap=".callFunction($event, 'mycustomString')" />
```

But im my case the event from the view doesn#t fire and i get no message in the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing parameters within the view to the controller function is firstly supported as of version 1.56 (maybe you are using an older one): https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/53b4b5ec2c83408a8da2cb6b9154c246

Comment: This may be the case since he is unsing the deprecated tap (now press) on the butotn.